# AngularJS Directive - compile is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

`ng-click` is not working. Can someone help me, how to use the `$compile`?

I have created a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/AhxGYnOsJ7rPqcQquMfq?p=preview

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

})
.directive('myDir', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'CAE',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      var dropdown = '';
      dropdown += '<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="'+ attrs.id +'">';
      dropdown += '<li role="presentation"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="alert(\'a\')">Actions</a></li>';
      dropdown += '</ul>';
      //dropdown = $compile(dropdown)(scope);
      element.after(dropdown);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: please update the Plunker, there is no directive there

Comment: Oopps.. I missed out. plunker link has been updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would pull out the click function into your controller. There is no `alert` on your controller's scope so it does nothing. Also, I try to avoid lots of nested quotes if possible. A simple and clean refactor.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.actionClick = function() {
        alert("a");
      }
})
.directive('myDir', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'CAE',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      var dropdown = '';
      dropdown += '<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="'+ attrs.id +'">';
      dropdown += '<li role="presentation"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="actionClick()">Actions</a></li>';
      dropdown += '</ul>';
      dropdown = $compile(dropdown)(scope);
      element.after(dropdown);
    }
  }
});
```

[see plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ozXjv1mV9fHCIWPfsKgA?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You were very close. Compile template with `$compile`:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function(){
      alert('d');
    };
})
.directive('myDir', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'CAE',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      var dropdown = '';
      dropdown += '<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="'+ attrs.id +'">';
      dropdown += '<li role="presentation"><a href="#" ng-click="doSomething()">Actions</a></li>';
      dropdown += '</ul>';

      var a_input = angular.element($compile(dropdown)(scope));

      element.append(a_input);
    }
  }
});
```

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/al443fFIlayrqqZowdHj?p=preview)**</kbd>

*comment*

AngularJS doesn't know about `alert`. If you want to call it from HTML, override it like @udidu showed.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is `angular.element` is really required?

Comment: some additional functionality: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element. But in your case you can remove it

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `ng-click` the ng-click directive searche for the expression in the current scope. Since their is no `alert` function on the directive's scope (or it's parent scope) then nothing happen.

You can add the `alert` function on your scope like so:

```
.directive('myDir', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'CAE',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){


          // add the alert function on the scope
          scope.alert = function(param) {
              alert(param);
          }


      var dropdown = '';
      dropdown += '<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="'+ attrs.id +'">';
      dropdown += '<li role="presentation"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="alert(\'a\')">Actions</a></li>';
      dropdown += '</ul>';
      dropdown = $compile(dropdown)(scope);
      element.after(dropdown);
    }
  }
});
```